# jquery datepicker not changing date format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

My jquery datepicker shows date in default format instead of `dd.mm.yy` however it is set in code. What is wrong ?

```
  $(function() {
    $("#startdatepicker")
      .datepicker({ minDate: -1, maxDate: "" }, "option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy");
    $("#enddatepicker").datepicker({
      onSelect: function() {
        $('#submit_button').removeClass("hidden");
        createDays();
      },
      minDate: -1,
      maxDate: "" }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $("#startdatepicker").on("change", function() {
       $("#enddatepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#startdatepicker").datepicker("getDate")).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
   });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dd-mm-yy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function incorrectly

Try

```
$("#startdatepicker")
  .datepicker({ minDate: -1, maxDate: "", "dateFormat": "dd.mm.yy"});
```

or

```
$("#startdatepicker")
  .datepicker({ minDate: -1, maxDate: "" });
$("#startdatepicker")
  .datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy");
```

See
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat